# quantile function through dfs of list

Tags: r, list, loops, quantile

I´ve got a zip (48GB) with 1800 .csv files and each file with 365 columns (days) and 22700 rows (observations). I need to calculate quantiles (5%, 50, and 95%) per each observations along a selected number of csv files.

So far, this has been my strategy:

First, I listed the selected .csv files as follow:

```
# selected csv
cas_list <-pharma$CAS.Number
cas_list <- paste0(cas_list, "_Ctot.csv")  #only 105 .csv files

# identify zipped file
zipped_file = "ctot_minus_invalids.zip"

# list selected csv
lst = vector("list", length(cas_list))

for (i in seq_along(cas_list))
  lst[[i]] = read.csv(unz(zipped_file, cas_list[i]), stringsAsFactors = F, check.names=FALSE)
```

So far so good, I ended up with a large list (105 elements, 7GB) having following structure:

```
> str(lst[1])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   22731 obs. of  368 variables:
  ..$                 : int [1:22731] 8000005 8115258 8115717 8000008 8102609 8103951 8000007 8000006 8205878 8205857 ...
  ..$ 2012/12/31_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.000000000000584 0.000000000008771 0.000000000006266 0.000000000000214 0.000000000004982 ...
  ..$ 2013/01/01_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.000000000000468 0.000000000007096 0.000000000005331 0.000000000000214 0.000000000004968 ...
  ..$ 2013/01/02_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.000000000000437 0.000000000005835 0.000000000005354 0.000000000000215 0.000000000004954 ...

> str(lst[2])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   22731 obs. of  368 variables:
  ..$                 : int [1:22731] 8000005 8115258 8115717 8000008 8102609 8103951 8000007 8000006 8205878 8205857 ...
  ..$ 2012/12/31_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.0000000000427 0.0000000006187 0.0000000004663 0.0000000000141 0.0000000003348 ...
  ..$ 2013/01/01_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.0000000000346 0.0000000005025 0.0000000004001 0.0000000000141 0.0000000003339 ...
  ..$ 2013/01/02_Cbulk: num [1:22731] 0.0000000000324 0.0000000004151 0.0000000004008 0.0000000000141 0.0000000003331 ...
```

Although this approach seems to be very memory intensive, it worked!.
Now, my issue is about how to apply a quantile function through each observation per df in the whole list. In order to have per each df in the list something like:

```
                   5%         50%       95%
 8000005   -0.6125624  0.09364346 2.0342648
 8115258   -1.4404549 -0.40036638 1.3918166
 8115717   -1.5614326 -0.08835999 1.5153081
 .... so on
```

I have tried the following code:

```
result <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  
  t(lapply(lst[i], quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), na.rm=T))
  
})

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(result), nrow=length(result), byrow=TRUE))
```

but I ended up with df that seems calculated quantiles per df only and it did not consider the observations :

```
                    X1               X2             X3
1   0.00000000000031103 0.00000000007249 0.000000001456
2   0.00000000000031103 0.00000000007249 0.000000001456
3   0.00000000000031103 0.00000000007249 0.000000001456
```

Do you have any idea of what is wrong in my quantile code?
Do you think in another more efficient way to do the same?
I will appreciate your feedback.

Comment: You may have to nest apply functions here.
something like 

```
lapply(lst, function(y) {sapply(y, function(x) {quantile(x[-1,], probs = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right. Maybe you are looking for this

```r
lst <- split(mtcars, mtcars$vs)
lapply(lst, function(x) t(sapply(x, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), na.rm=T)))
#> $`0`
#>            5%    50%       95%
#> mpg   10.4000  15.65  21.75000
#> cyl    5.7000   8.00   8.00000
#> disp 141.2950 311.00 461.80000
#> hp   107.1500 180.00 274.65000
#> drat   2.9045   3.18   4.25150
#> wt     2.5480   3.57   5.35685
#> qsec  14.5850  17.02  17.98300
#> vs     0.0000   0.00   0.00000
#> am     0.0000   0.00   1.00000
#> gear   3.0000   3.00   5.00000
#> carb   2.0000   4.00   6.30000
#> 
#> $`1`
#>           5%      50%      95%
#> mpg  17.9950  22.8000  32.9250
#> cyl   4.0000   4.0000   6.0000
#> disp 74.0900 120.5500 236.5500
#> hp   58.5000  96.0000 123.0000
#> drat  2.9680   3.9200   4.4685
#> wt    1.5793   2.6225   3.4470
#> qsec 17.8100  19.1700  21.1580
#> vs    1.0000   1.0000   1.0000
#> am    0.0000   0.5000   1.0000
#> gear  3.0000   4.0000   4.3500
#> carb  1.0000   1.5000   4.0000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I do get `> lapply(lst, function(x) t(sapply(x, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95), na.rm=T)))
[[1]]
    
[1,]

[[2]]
    
[1,]` an empty object

Comment: can you give a small example of your data? using `dput`

Comment: Finally I managed to run it. I used `chem_quantiles <- lapply(chem_list, function(x) {
  df <- apply(x, 1, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95),  na.rm = TRUE)
  out<- t(df)})`